# Autoregressive distributed lag models ADL(p,q): seeking "how to" preferably in Matlab (Stata/R/Python/C# etc)

Tags: matlab, model-selection, stata, lags, ardl

Could anyone provide me the details of how to determine the lag order of the  distributed lags for an $\text{ADL}(p,q)$ model in Matlab or another statistical package (and very much preferably in combination with the autoregression lags)?

Full working examples with model selection criteria ($\text{AIC}$ and $\text{BIC}$) seem to be available on the Matlab website for $\text{VAR}$ models, $\text{ARMA}$ models etc. but I can't find one for the $\text{ADL}(p,q)$ model. I would not have a clue how to rewrite those models to $\text{ADL}(p,q)$ myself but I have a vague feeling that such a thing would be possible.

In the end I want to automate this analysis by first checking the lag orders $p$, and $q$ and then using these numbers automatically to create the regressions out of this. So basically I'm looking for a fully working example. (I want to skip part of adding and deleting regressors by hand as much as possible to get a quick idea of the distributed lags of several assets).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a request for code. Nor are such questions widely welcomed on Stack Overflow. It may be that software-specific forums would be more receptive, but in general "please give me complete code" questions have low success probability anywhere unless tutorials already exist (in which case you should be able to find them). For general advice, see http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic Rewriting this question to increase its statistical content might increase its appeal and pertinence here.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I need just the algorithms to calculate the ADL's (which I can't find and don't really understand).

Comment: or model selection criteria methods that could be used to create and estimate a ADL(p,q). It is not meant as a request for complete code.

Comment: As suggested therefore, you are well advised to rewrite the question accordingly. Even the title implies that you are seeking code primarily.

Comment: Would a title change and a remaining first alinea be sufficient to make it more attractive??? I am not really sure why this question would not be supportive to the community or less attractive to answer. Hmmzz I need some advice very badly on this topic.

Comment: I can't promise what forum members might do. In principle one person willing to help could be enough. How much you need help is not a criterion of merit here. All questions are presumed important to those who ask, but they are not equally interesting or intelligible to those who might answer. (I have never used or read about those models, so can only act as traffic cop.)

Comment: For Stata see this thread http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/95329-ardl-in-stata

Comment: thanks, looks like a good start although some details are still a little vague to me